# How to get user-defined start of week in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, weekday

I know that I can get the start of the week according to the user's locale by using `Calendar.current.firstWeekday`, but I can change the start of the week from the locale's default in Settings > Calendar > Start Week On.

How can I get the first weekday that's been selected in that pane? Or do I need to allow users to set this in my app?

Comment: That's the settings for "Calendar" app. You don't have to (or shouldn't) use the app settings. You can see `Settings > Calendar > Start Week` also respects system settings by default (`Calendar.current.firstWeekday`).